# How do I create random dot sizes using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm able to produce this plot with random colors, now I just need random dot sizes.
My X and Y values are explict and must stay this way.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy


x = list(range(1,31))
y = [.027, 8.39, 0.08, 6.41, 1.79, 21.57,2.65, 0.75,3.35,0.82,3.41,1.11,5.84,3.88,3.67,9.08, 2.11,7.09,2.30,0.80,0.32,0.36,11.70,0.89,1.00,0.09,7.11,1.22,0.32,0.34]

#size = 100 * numpy.random.rand(y)
plt.title('Scatter Plot')
plt.xlabel('Observations')
plt.ylabel('Data')
plt.scatter(x,y, c=numpy.random.rand(len(x),3))
```

'

[image: Plot Picture]

Answer (score 1):

You set the size of the scatter dots by the parameter `s`.

For instance:

```
size = 100*numpy.random.rand(len(y))
```

and

```
plt.scatter(x,y, c=numpy.random.rand(len(x),3), s=size)
```

will give something like this:

[image]